# php code to check for repeating characters / bogus text

Tags: php, string, full-text-search

i'm running a dating site and there is a place where people enter their profile - I already have a bad-words filter but now I have a problem where people enter a profile that is just garbage characters or just "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "--------------" etc. I'm looking for an effective way of filtering out the long words of repeated characters. thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could check why people aren't filling in your profile? Requiring a pagefull of data on registration tends to bore people, so they just fill in garbage. What you could do is ask just for the basic fields on registration, and then display a progress bar somewhere on the page ("your profile is 10% complete, fill in birthdate to get to 20%"). That's the way many sites (e.g. FB) do this, and it actually motivates the users better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it (but it will replace double-characters too, mabe you need to edit a bit):

```
preg_replace('{(.)\1+}','$1',$text);
```

OT: *can't belive there are still people who use [bad-word](http://www.customerserviceftw.com/2009/10/28/disney-thinks-my-last-name-is-a-naughty-word/) [filters](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)...*

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need some [bayesian spam filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)-alike filter for that kind of stuff.

> Particular words have particular probabilities of occurring in spam email and in legitimate email. For instance, most email users will frequently encounter the word "Viagra" in spam email, but will seldom see it in other email. The filter doesn't know these probabilities in advance, and must first be trained so it can build them up. To train the filter, the user must manually indicate whether a new email is spam or not.
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a word-list, and flag each message that has long words (e.g. 5+ chars) not on the list - if the field contains 5 8-letter words, of which none are in a dictionary, it's *likely* it's not meaningful data.